# What is the purpose of setting a DataMember Name

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

It might sound like a very dumb question but I didn't find a suitable answer after googling.

When you can access a Datamember directly using the property name what is the purpose of explicitly setting a data member name as shown below in bracket next to datamember attribute.

```
[DataMember(Name = "Status")]
public string Status { get; set; }
```

Comment: Have you read the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)? It's pretty explicit: When applied to the member of a type, specifies that the member is part of a data contract and is serializable by the DataContractSerializer

Comment: Most relevant part: _By default, the CLR member name is used as the name of the data member. By setting the Name property, you can customize the name of the data member_

Comment: Yes thats what I am seeking why would a customization of the name be helpful. Let say if Status property is self explanatory why would i add Name to datamember. Just adding the Datamember to the Status property will make it serializable

Comment: I am more concerned about those usage scenarios which can't be achieved without these customization of name.

Answer (score 3):

The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.name(v=vs.110).aspx) are pretty good actually:

> The Name property enables you to **use names that are not permitted as
>   common language runtime (CLR) identifiers.** In addition, this property
>   enables the type author to define a data member name separate from the
>   CLR member name. This separate definition helps in **versioning
>   scenarios** (changing the CLR member name without breaking the data
>   contract) and allows a **different naming convention** for data contact
>   members and CLR members.

Answer (score 2):

Datamember.Name just defines the representation of this property in the serialized form.

It is pretty handy if you serialize to JSON for example because in JavaScript you usually want to work with camelCased variables and in C# your models should have PascalCased names...

Also, read the remarks in the [official docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.name(v=vs.110).aspx), might help you to understand that, too.

Comment: See the competing answer.